# Loading image after second Volley JSON request into a RecyclerView using Picasso?

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, android-volley, soundcloud

I am making use of the Soundcloud API and displaying the search results into a RecyclerView that I have created. In my RecyclerView, each element is inside of a cardView, which contains a textView, for the title of the search result, and an imageView, for the image/album art of the result. The way that the Soundcloud API works is that when you are searching for something, it will provide you with the track IDs, titles, and other information for all of the search results. But, it does not include the album art URLs in the search result response. In order to get the album art for the search results, I must create separate JSON requests for each of the search results that I get back from the primary JSON request using the track IDs. I am perplexed on how and when to request the secondary JSONs via Volley.

Currently, I am issuing the secondary requests with the `onBindViewHolder` method of my RecyclerView Adapter class. This does work, but one minor problem that is present with this implementation is that when I scroll down a couple results on the screen and immediately scroll back up, some of the images get misplaced and are put into the wrong elements and the proper images take a couple seconds to load back in. This happens because the images are recycled and the `onBindViewHolder` method is only called when an element of the RecyclerView needs to be rendered or re-rendered. So, does anyone have a solution as to when I could make the secondary JSON requests for the album art?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `ListView` rather than a `RecyclerView`. That way your cells aren't recycled, and you don't have to worry about each cell being destroyed. The trade off is that you don't have the performance of the `RecyclerView`, but it might be worth it in this case.